# How to enable captcha after multiple failed login attempts from same ip in Node?

Tags: node.js, express, captcha, recaptcha

I am using `express.basicAuth` to login, right now without any database. Here's my `auth.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');

var admins = {
  admin@foo.com': { password: 'Passw0rd1' },
  michael@foo.com': { password: 'Passw0rd2' },
};

var handler = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {
  var u = admins[user];
  if (!u) return false;
  return u.password === pass;
});


module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  return handler(req, res, function(err) {
    req.admin = req.remoteUser;
    res.local('admin', req.remoteUser);
    return next(err);
  });
};
```

I have noticed that my service is under brute force attacks, same ip trying to login by enumerating the possibilities.

To discourage future attacks, I would like to add the ability to redirect user to Recaptcha service after 3 failed login attempts.

I used the [node-recaptcha](https://github.com/mirhampt/node-recaptcha) module successfully but I don't know how to integrate it with `basicAuth` and to keep track of the ips.

Any ideas ?

Comment: why not just lock the account for 30 minutes.

Comment: @chovy the attacker tries to login by enumerating usernames. Should I keep counter of logins attempts for each IP i get ? The list could blow up pretty quickly

Comment: ips aren't a good way. I would just track how many times attempts an account has, and lock it for 30 minutes after 6.

Comment: @chovy Any idea on how to implement this without database ?